# Good replacement for 74HC573N Octal Trans D-Type Latch?

Tags: latch, obsolescence

Does anyone have any recommendations on what to use? I suppose any 5V, reasonably broad temperature range (automotive application) latch would work, but if there's something people like, I'm game!
I don't need to be pin compliant as I'm spinning a new board.

-------Edit:
I should add that the few places which DID have the exact part wanted well over $20 each for them, making them the most expensive part of the project by an order of magnitude!

That said, the advice to just switch packages (I was keeping the socketed 20 pin DIP in order not to scare off a customer who just wanted "more of these cards I ran out of") seems to be the way to roll, and the parts are totally reasonable as suggested by answers here.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: I'd think a good replacement would be another 74HC573. Why do you want something different?

Comment: Where in the world are you that you can't get an 'HC573 in DIP!?!? I have two of them installed in the board sitting next to me... Or are you seeking to make the board smaller/get rid of through-hole parts?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel At least NXP has made that package variant obsolete, as far as I can see. This question is still somewhat puzzling, though.

Comment: @pipe -- [TI still makes 'em](https://store.ti.com/SN74HC573AN.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use the [`74HC573D`](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/logic/hct/octal-d-type-transparent-latch-3-state:74HC573D), in an SO-20 package. If you don't have enough room on your board, the TSSOP-20 variant [`74HC573PW`](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/logic/hct/octal-d-type-transparent-latch-3-state:74HC573PW) is a good choice, with a much smaller body size.

You may want to use the SO-20 if you're etching your own PCB, but the TSSOP-20 should be easy to use if you have a good quality [ENIG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroless_nickel_immersion_gold) board with a solder mask.